Flutter app crashes after injecting markers into google maps
My application contains a google map screen, I need to fetch the locations from the api,
my viewModel looks as follow:
class MapViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
    MapRepo repo = MapRepo();
    List<VendorBranchModel> branches = [];
    Set<Marker> markers = {};
    bool isMapLoading = true;

    setMapLoading(bool val) {
      isMapLoading = val;
      notifyListeners();
    }

    void prepareMarkers() {
      markers =  branches.map((branch) {
        return Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(branch.id ?? ""),
          position: LatLng(branch.latitude ?? 0.0, branch.longitude ?? 0.0),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: branch.englishBranchName,
            snippet: branch.phoneNumber,
          ),
        );
      }).toSet();
      setMapLoading(false);

    }

    Future<void> getBranchesAPI({ required Function(String?) onError}) async {
        setMapLoading(true);
        var response = await repo.getBranches(pageNumber: MapConstants.pageNumber,
            pageSize: MapConstants.pageSize ,body: {});
        response.when( success: (NetworkBaseModel response) async {
          if (response.isSuccess == true) {
            branches = response.data;
            prepareMarkers();
          }
        }, failure: (NetworkExceptions error) {
          onError(error.message);
          setMapLoading(false);

        });
    }
}

The Screen, which im updating, looks as following:
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (BuildContext context) => viewModel
          ..getBranchesAPI(
              onError: (error) => ToastManager.showToast(error ?? "")
          ),
        child: Scaffold(
            body: Column(children: [
          CustomSearchView(
            onSearch: (keyword) {},
            onFilter: (filters) {
              filterRequest.orderFilter = filters;
              AppLogs.debugLog(filters.toJson());
            },
          ),
        Expanded(
            child: Consumer<MapViewModel>(
              builder: (context, viewModel, child) {
                return viewModel.isMapLoading
                    ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                    : GoogleMapsScreen(markers: viewModel.markers);
              },
            ),
        )
        ])));

And the google maps widget as follow:
class GoogleMapsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Set<Marker> markers;
  GoogleMapsScreen({super.key, required this.markers});

  @override
  State<GoogleMapsScreen> createState() => _GoogleMapsScreenState();
}

class _GoogleMapsScreenState extends State<GoogleMapsScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return
      GoogleMap(initialCameraPosition:
      CameraPosition(target: widget.markers.isNotEmpty ? widget.markers.first.position : LatLng(33.8938, 35.5018)),
        markers: widget.markers,
      );
  }
}

whenever the api loads, and the map takes the marker, the app crashes with no error message.
while when sending empty markers, the map shows in an empty state.
Any help would be great here.

From what you've described, it sounds like the crash might be due to updating the markers in the GoogleMapsScreen widget while the widget itself is being built or rendered. This can happen if widget.markers is updated and then re-rendered, leading to inconsistencies in the widget's state. Here are a few steps and improvements to help troubleshoot and potentially resolve this issue:
Set Initial State for Markers: When GoogleMapsScreen is initialized, ensure the markers Set has a default value to avoid any unexpected nulls. Additionally, it might be useful to explicitly update the markers with setState when the markers are updated.
Add Error Handling for API Responses: Ensure that the response data from getBranchesAPI is well-structured and valid before proceeding to create markers. Sometimes, malformed data can lead to unexpected issues without clear error messages.
Handle Markers State with a Key: Add a unique key to GoogleMapsScreen to force the widget to rebuild properly when the markers set updates.
Here are the adjusted sections of your code with these suggestions:

Modify GoogleMapsScreen to Ensure Proper Marker State Handling
Use widget.markers with a unique key to force rebuilds and set a default position if the markers are empty.
class GoogleMapsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
final Set markers;
GoogleMapsScreen({super.key, required this.markers});
@override
State createState() => _GoogleMapsScreenState();
}
class _GoogleMapsScreenState extends State {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GoogleMap(
initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
target: widget.markers.isNotEmpty
? widget.markers.first.position
: LatLng(33.8938, 35.5018), // Default location if no markers
zoom: 10, // Adjust zoom level as needed
),
markers: widget.markers,
key: ValueKey(widget.markers), // Use ValueKey to force rebuild on marker change
);
}
}

Update prepareMarkers in MapViewModel to Verify Marker Data
Check that each branch has valid coordinates before adding a marker to avoid crashes from null or invalid data.
void prepareMarkers() {
markers = branches.where((branch) => branch.latitude != null && branch.longitude != null).map((branch) {
return Marker(
markerId: MarkerId(branch.id ?? ""),
position: LatLng(branch.latitude ?? 0.0, branch.longitude ?? 0.0),
infoWindow: InfoWindow(
title: branch.englishBranchName ?? "No Name",
snippet: branch.phoneNumber ?? "No Phone",
),
);
}).toSet();
setMapLoading(false);
}

Add Debugging to Track Errors
Add debugging lines in getBranchesAPI to capture and log unexpected issues that might not be obvious otherwise.
Future getBranchesAPI({ required Function(String?) onError}) async {
setMapLoading(true);
try {
var response = await repo.getBranches(
pageNumber: MapConstants.pageNumber,
pageSize: MapConstants.pageSize,
body: {},
);
response.when(
success: (NetworkBaseModel response) async {
if (response.isSuccess == true) {
branches = response.data;
prepareMarkers();
} else {
onError("Failed to load data");
}
},
failure: (NetworkExceptions error) {
onError(error.message);
setMapLoading(false);
},
);
} catch (e) {
onError("An unexpected error occurred: $e");
setMapLoading(false);
}
}

Check Markers in the Consumer
Use the Consumer to ensure viewModel.markers is not empty before displaying the map:
Expanded(
child: Consumer(
builder: (context, viewModel, child) {
if (viewModel.isMapLoading) {
return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
} else if (viewModel.markers.isEmpty) {
return Center(child: Text("No locations available"));
} else {
return GoogleMapsScreen(markers: viewModel.markers);
}
},
),


)
This approach will help track down any issues and ensure that GoogleMapsScreen has consistent and valid data when rendering markers.

I followed your steps one by one, still its crashing after getting the api response, the response is successfully retrieved, im just getting after the crash the following:
Lost connection to device.
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

Make sure you're not running out of memory or other resources. This can happen if the markers are being created in a loop without proper cleanup. Ensure that the branches list and markers are not excessively large.
